# Explanation of `stack test --test-arguments "-m "<filter>""`

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack, hspec

On other [forum pages](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/2210), I've seen that I can run specific [`hspec`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hspec) tests with the command

```
stack test --test-arguments "-m "<filter>""
```

where `<filter>` is set to match [`it`'s](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hspec-2.4.4/docs/Test-Hspec.html#v:it) textual descriptor for the intended tests. I frequently use this command to run single tests of interest without having to run the entire test suite.

**But I do not understand how exactly this command specifies that.** For instance, what kind of argument is `"-m "<filter>""`, and what does that "-m" mean? What other arguments can be specified as the `"-m "<filter>""` is here?

About `--test-arguments`, `stack test --help | less` says only

```
--ta,--test-arguments TEST_ARGS
                       Arguments passed in to the test suite program
```

which is the only relevant documentation I have found on how to specify stack to run a subset of tests.

Comment: Is [this](http://hspec.github.io/options.html) what you are looking for? Stack just passes `test-arguments` to the testing library, so it makes sense `stack test --help` wouldn't be able to tell you the options `hspec` has.

Comment: @Alec I hadn't seen that, thanks.